# How to show two figures using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some troubles while drawing two figures at the same time, not shown in a single plot. But according to the documentation, I wrote the code and only the figure one shows.  I think maybe I lost something important. Could anyone help me to figure out? Thanks.  (The *tlist_first* used in the code is a list of data.)

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.hist(tlist_first, bins=2000000, normed = True, histtype ="step", cumulative = True, color = 'g',label = 'first answer')
plt.ylabel('Percentage of answered questions')
plt.xlabel('Minutes elapsed after questions are posted')

plt.axvline(x = 30, ymin = 0, ymax = 1, color = 'r', linestyle = '--', label = '30 min')
plt.axvline(x = 60, ymin = 0, ymax = 1, color = 'c', linestyle = '--', label = '1 hour')
plt.legend()
plt.xlim(0,120)
plt.ylim(0,1) 
plt.show()
plt.close() ### not working either with this line or without it

plt.figure(2)
plt.hist(tlist_first, bins=2000000, normed = True, histtype ="step", cumulative = True, color = 'g',label = 'first answer')

plt.ylabel('Percentage of answered questions')
plt.xlabel('Minutes elapsed after questions are posted')

plt.axvline(x = 240, ymin = 0, ymax = 1, color = 'r', linestyle = '--', label = '30 min')
plt.axvline(x = 1440, ymin = 0, ymax = 1, color = 'c', linestyle = '--', label = '1 hour')
plt.legend(loc= 4)
plt.xlim(0,2640)
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Alternatively to calling `plt.show()` at the end of the script, you can also control each figure separately doing:

```
f = plt.figure(1)
plt.hist........
............
f.show()

g = plt.figure(2)
plt.hist(........
................
g.show()

raw_input()
```

In this case you must call `raw_input` to keep the figures alive.
This way you can select dynamically which figures you want to show

Note: `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()` in Python 3

Comment: Unfortunately with python3.6 and latest matplotlib, calling several fig.show() seems to show nothing. I still have to call plt.show() at the end.

Comment: @kakyo - Using Python `3.6.6` with Matplotlib `2.2.2` (which was the latest release at time of your writing); the solution above works for me. Your problem must come from something else, e.g. the [backend](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) used. Running `matplotlib.get_backend()`, I get `'Qt5Agg'`

Comment: I also had to add `figure=g` to the second `plt.hist()`.

Comment: do I need other packages? `NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined`

Comment: @zheyuanWang If you are using python 3 you must use `input()`. See last note in the post

Answer (score 65):

You should call `plt.show()` only at the end after creating all the plots.

Comment: I found this quite annoying, since if I called `show()` once, I cannot call it again, if I want to show the plot again, I have to replot it again?

Comment: I think it's reasonable to have the functionality to show the plot every time I call it.

Answer (score 39):

I had this same problem.

Did:

```
f1 = plt.figure(1)

# code for figure 1

# don't write 'plt.show()' here


f2 = plt.figure(2)

# code for figure 2

plt.show()
```

Write 'plt.show()' only once, after the last figure.
Worked for me.

Comment: This is the same as the answer [from janneb back in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7744803/3126298)

Comment: This shows it in the same window, not 2 separate windows. Answers OP's question though. Upvote therefore.

Comment: But what if you want a separate plot? it was plotted on the same plot

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively, I would suggest turning interactive on in the beginning and at the very last plot, turn it off. All will show up, but they will not disappear as your program will stay around until you close the figures.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import interactive

plt.figure(1)
... code to make figure (1)

interactive(True)
plt.show()

plt.figure(2)
... code to make figure (2)

plt.show()

plt.figure(3)
... code to make figure (3)

interactive(False)
plt.show()
```