# multiple figures in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am actually new here and i just started python for my master thesis project. I try to plot multiple figures but i can't. i have looked many same questions and answers but still, i can't get a result.

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.draw()
plt.axis([14,55, 3, 5])
plt.xlabel('doy')
plt.ylabel('amplitudes of L1 & L2 signals')
red_dot, = plt.plot(X1, L1,'ro')
green_dot, = plt.plot(X1, L2, 'go')
plt.legend([red_dot, green_dot], ["L1", "L2"])



plt.figure(2)
plt.draw() 
plt.axis([14,55, 25, 60])
plt.xlabel('doy')
plt.ylabel('dampenings of L1 & L2 signals')
red_dot, = plt.plot(X1, damp_L1,'ro')
green_dot, = plt.plot(X1, damp_L2, 'go')
plt.legend([red_dot, green_dot], ["dampening of L1", "dampening of L2"])


plt.show()
```

This is what i have written and the only thing i get is a FIGURE 1 with the first plot and an empty FIGURE2 window with no data inside!'
Can somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show two figures using matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744697/how-to-show-two-figures-using-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using the OO interface as much as possible (instead of the pyplot 'state machine' API).  What you want is something like:

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()

ax1.plot(x, y, 'ro')

ax2.plot(x, y, 'go')
```

Running these commands an ipython session (after doing `%matplotlib`) will give you two interactive figures to play with.

Comment: thank you for the answer my friend. I did as you said:
    fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.plot(X1, L1, 'ro', X1, L2, 'go')
    ax2.plot(X1, damp_L1, 'ro', X1, damp_L2, 'go')
    plt.show()

but all i get is two figures with 4 dots. 1 green and 1 red !

Comment: A. Drosi, tcaswell answer is correct. Maybe all plots are not showing because you wrongly define ```plt.axis``` on each figure? If you do not show an example of X1, L1,... arrays, this answer is the most someone can help you

Comment: Hi  guys. I worked it in some other way. I didn't doubt about the given answer though @iblasi! Anyway, i did sth that looks quite strange but works. I created 2 lists and put the data in these two lists. Then, i just plotted the lists and used also plt.figure(1) and plt.figure(2) and it worked.