# How to include multiple graphs in one window

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am currently using Atom and when i run my code the output graphs are being shown in a sequential order such that I can only see the next graph after closing the first graph.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

housing = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\<username>\\handson-ml\\datasets\\housing\\housing.csv")

housing.hist(bins=50, figsize=(20,15))
plt.show()


housing["income_cat"] = np.ceil(housing["median_income"]/1.5)
housing["income_cat"].where(housing["income_cat"]<5, 5.0, inplace=True)

plt.hist(housing["income_cat"])
plt.show()
```

How to correct this so as to see all the graphs simultaneously? Being used to Jupyter I am having trouble performing data visualization on other platforms.

Comment: Voted to reopen; this question asks how to display all figures at once, the flagged duplicate is on how to create `subplots` in one figure, which is something completely different.

Comment: This might be what you are actually after: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744697/how-to-show-two-figures-using-matplotlib

Answer (score 2):

Define plot axis and specify it when you make the first hist. Then make twin axis and use to plot the second one. Parameter `alpha` allows you to distinguish hists.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

housing = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\<username>\\handson-ml\\datasets\\housing\\housing.csv")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
housing.hist(bins=50, figsize=(20,15), ax=ax, alpha=.2)

housing["income_cat"] = np.ceil(housing[1]/1.5)
housing["income_cat"].where(housing["income_cat"]<5, 5.0, inplace=True)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
housing['income_cat'].hist(ax=ax2, color='r', alpha=.2)
plt.show()
```

Use `plt.show()` at the end to show the figure once.