# Displaying two data files using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, raster

I have two CSV files that produce a raster image, each are 300x300.

I can get the program to display one, but if I try to display both, it just produces a blank white graph. All I want it to show is the two sets of data as separate images, it does not need to be changed in any way.

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

lidar = []  # height of object
radar = []  # texture of object

with open('lidar1.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in reader:
        rowlist = []
        for value in row:
            rowlist.append(value) 
        lidar.append(rowlist)


with open('radar1.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in reader:
        rowlist = []
        for value in row:
            rowlist.append(value) 
        radar.append(rowlist)

plt.imshow(lidar)
```

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show two figures using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744697/how-to-show-two-figures-using-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `plt.show` to plot each figure separately:

```
plt.imshow(lidar) 
plt.show()
plt.imshow(radar)
plt.show()
```

Or do like @norok2 suggested by using subplots

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = [10, 20])
ax[0].imshow(lidar)
ax[1].imshow(radar)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 figures so that they display separately as so.

```
f1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(lidar)
f2 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(rowlist)
```

Comment: when i do that, i get two separate figures displayed as a line graph, rather than two raster images.